# Python argparse: Get name of subparser program in help string

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

I'm writing an argument parser for a python module with various subparsers.  My objective is to have an argument that's shared whose Argument constructor is passed to multiple children:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser(prog = 'master')
parser1 = ArgumentParser(help = None)
parser1.add_argument('foo', type = int, help = 'Number of times to process %(prog)s') # Line of interest
parser2 = ArgumentParser(help = None)
parser2.add_argument('--bar', type = int, default = 0, help = 'Start at this number')
parser3 = ArgumentParser(help = None)
parser3.add_argument('--baz', type = str, default = 'DEFAULT', help = 'Init file with this text')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
sp1 = subparsers.add_parser('prog1', parents = [parser1, parser2])
sp2 = subparsers.add_parser('prog2', parents = [parser1, parser3])
parser.parse_args('prog1 -h'.split())
```

The desired output would be something like

```
usage: master prog1 [-h] [--bar BAR] foo

positional arguments:
  foo            Number of times to process prog1

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this message and exit
  --bar          Start at this number
```

When I use this exact setup, i get `master prog1` instead of `prog1` in the help string for `foo`.  What should i change in the line marked `#Line of interest` to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I would use [Click_](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) for what you are trying to do.

[Click_](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) in three points:

1. arbitrary nesting of commands
2. automatic help page generation
3. supports lazy loading of subcommands at runtime

Answer (score 0):

I can explain what is going on, but may not be able offer a solution.

The short answer is that the `sp1.prog` is used both in its `usage` format and as the `%(prog)s` value in the help lines.  And it is constructed with that `usage` line in mind.

---

```
sp1 = subparsers.add_parser('prog1', parents = [parser1, parser2])
```

creates a parser, and adds arguments from the `parents`.  `add_parser` is a method of the `class _SubParsersAction` (the subparser Action class).  And the `prog` attribute for that parser is created with:

```
     if kwargs.get('prog') is None:
        kwargs['prog'] = '%s %s' % (self._prog_prefix, name)
```

You should be able to see this attribute with `print(sp1.prog)` (I expect 'master prog1').  That's the value that is used in the `usage` line, and in any of the help lines with `%(prog)s`.

`subparsers._prog_prefix` is derived from `parser.prog` (see the `add_subparsers` code for details).  But you can also specify a `prog` parameter:

```
sp1 = subparsers.add_parser('prog1', parents = [parser1, parser2], prog='prog1')
```

That should correct the string in the `help` line.  But it will also change the string the `usage`.

You could also give the subparser an explicit `usage`:

```
sp1 = subparsers.add_parser('prog1', parents = [parser1, parser2], prog='prog1', usage='master prog1 ...')
```

Without doing surgery to the `HelpFormatter` I don't think you can change `prog` in the help lines without also changing it in the usage.

And given the way `parents` works you can't change the help line for `prog1 foo` without also changing it for `prog2 foo`.  `parents` copies Action objects by reference, so the two subparsers share the `foo` Action object.

You many have to abandon the `parents` approach, at least for this argument, and hardcode the name.  If you need to add the argument to multiple subparsers, write a little utility function to facilitate that.  The `parents` mechanism is just (usually) a convenience, something that saves some typing/editing.

---

This modified script will illustrate my points

```
parser = ArgumentParser(prog = 'master')

parser1 = ArgumentParser(add_help = False)
fooarg=parser1.add_argument('foo', type = int, help = 'foo prog: %(prog)s') # Line of interest
parser2 = ArgumentParser(add_help = False)
parser2.add_argument('--bar', type = int, default = 0, help = 'Start at this number')
parser3 = ArgumentParser(add_help = False)
parser3.add_argument('--baz', type = str, default = 'DEFAULT', help = 'Init file with this text')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(prog='subparsers')
sp1 = subparsers.add_parser('prog1', parents = [parser1, parser2], prog='name1')
sp2 = subparsers.add_parser('prog2', parents = [parser1, parser3])

#parser.print_help()

# fooarg is an Action for both subparsers
# print(fooarg.help)
# fooarg.help = 'FOO HELP'

print('==>sp1 prog:', sp1.prog)
sp1.print_help()
print('==>sp2 prog:', sp2.prog)
sp2.print_help()

sp1.prog = 'custom'
sp1.print_help()

# addition
fooarg.default = 'default'
fooarg.metavar = 'META'
fooarg.help = 'prog: %(prog)s, dest=%(dest)s, nargs=%(nargs)s, type=%(type)s, default=%(default)s'
sp1.print_help()
```

This last bit adds a bunch of Action attributes to the help.  But `prog` is the only one that comes from the `parser`:

```
positional arguments:
  META        prog: custom, dest=foo, nargs=None, type=int, default=default
```